# Wallpapers app iOS

Tags: ios, imageview

I'm just trying to create a simple app, that would work as a wallpaper app. But i need to get the images off interwebs. So I thought I would get a rss feed of images and and basically have a rss reader that only has images.  But I thought. . . I need a preview for the images in the main viewcontroller, so I would use just a image view for that, but it needs to be able to let the user be able to click on the preview image and take the user to another viewcontroller that will have the full size image.  So should I try to put the preview images in a button? and let the button take the user to another viewcontroller with a full size imageview and somehow have the image display their. Sorry if this is confusing, this is the only way i thought how to do this.   If their is an easier way, please tell me.   And when it comes to, when the user wants to download the image online, i can just hook up some outlets for some buttons on the viewcontroller and link them together with the image, and put some code for saving the image. Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so let me get this straight:

You want to create an app that retrieves images from the internet, displays them to the user, and when the user clicks on an image, he/she is presented with a fullscreen view of that image?

There are a number of options you can pick from. Here are just a few suggestions:

- You can use the `image` as the `image` for a `UIButton`
- You can make the `UIImageView` call a function when it's tapped (using either a `UIGestureRecognizer`, or just implementing the `touchesBegan:` method).
- You can put an invisible `UIButton` over the `UIImageView`

When displaying the image, you add an `UIImageView` to the `UIViewController` and hook it up using an `IBOutlet` (unless you're creating the layout in code). Then in the code, you would convert the downloaded image (`NSData`) into a `UIImage`, and then display this in the `UIImageView`.

---

It seems as you're a beginning iOS Developer, and I respect that you're trying to learn by doing. However, I suggest that you start off with reading some introductory tutorials before you begin your first project. Otherwise you might waste a lot of time. [Here's a very good guide on how to get started](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/how-to-become-a-badass-ios-developer-a87a1c78f609)! Good luck :)